# Deleting listbox items in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I can't figure out how to correctly remove items from winform listbox in c#.

The listbox is populated with some string from `FileSystemWatcher` which basically puts in the listbox which files are modified.

Then I've made a "Search" function which remove items that doesn't contain what the user inputs in a textbox.

here's the code

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text) && lstFileEvents.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstFileEvents.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!lstFileEvents.Items[i].ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text))
            {
                lstFileEvents.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        lstFileEvents.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Actually I've tried many approaches, looking through various stackoverflow questions and google results like:

- Using .RemoveAt()
- Using Update() instead of Refresh()
- Clearing the listbox and updating listbox.DataSource directly, then refreshing/update
- Make a dummy ListBox.ObjectCollection, applying the search/remove on that and then assigning it as a datasource and refreshing/update.
- Other I don't remember

Well nothing is working. The list stays there and debugging didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

listbox population code:

```
void fswFileWatch_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    fswFileWatch.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    WriteListbox("Renamed: ", e);
    fswFileWatch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

public void WriteListbox(string msg, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //Some filter which works fine
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtExcludeFilter.Text))
    {
        foreach (string Filter in txtExcludeFilter.Text.Split(','))
        {
            //some other filter
            if (!e.FullPath.Contains(Filter))
            {
                //here's where I populate the list
                lstFileEvents.Items.Add(msg + e.FullPath);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lstFileEvents.Items.Add(msg + e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you could use the `AutoCompleteMode` listbox property, `SuggestAppend`. This will shorten the list selection depending on what is in the text field.

Comment: @GrantWinney Added to the question
@ Ben Wha Exactly it does? I don't think I understood

Comment: The properties of a listbox has an `AutoCompleteMode`, and the `SuggestAppend` option will shorten the list of options a user can select from depending on what they input to the listbox. For example, if I type in "T", the drawer will shorten to all the entries with a "T" in it. If I type in "Text" it will shorten the list to items that contain the word "text", and so on.

Comment: Well actually it's ok like this. If an user wants to search for evertything that contains "doc" he should find lines like "Documents", "docs", "doctor" all togheter, and the search it's already acting like this. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cabccca-f2b9-40c4-9cf5-89cbcbc06f03/remove-selected-items-from-listbox-when-pressed-delete-button?forum=csharplanguage) suggests removing the list items in reverse.
First set:

```
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
```

Then reverse remove:

```
for (int i = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndices[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, this works.
Could you explain more if you have some clues? In the original question I was saying I'm a 2 year experience programmer and that I was appalled by this awkward logic as I couldn't remove list items properly though it seemed a trivial task.

Why you do have to do it backwards? Sounds ridiculous

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Windows so I can't check the .NET Framework for Listbox.ObjectCollection and see how it works under the hood. I would guess that the logic would be based on the type of data structure that is. I even read the API [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) and it doesn't mention anything. Lastly, it may be a bug in the framework that was never fixed / documented. Sorry I couldn't be more help.